# counting the number of times a while loop executes works until it is placed within a for loop (the same output repeats over and over)

Tags: r

I need to count the number of times this while loop executes, and I am able to do that for one instance.  However, I want to make this happen several times and record all of the loop-counts in a vector.

The following code gives me a count of the number of times the while loop executes (can vary based on the result of the `sample()` function):

```
x= 0
count = 0

while (x < 10) {
  y = sample(c(1,2), 1, c(.50,.50), replace = T)
  x = x+y
  count = count+1
}
count
```

This works perfectly. Gives me a single number which can vary randomly but for the sake of discussion I'll assume it is `8`.

However, when I place that in a for loop:

```
x= 0
count = 0
counts = c()

for (i in 1:5) {
  while (x < 10) {
    y = sample(c(1,2), 1, c(.50,.50), replace = T)
    x = x+y
    count = count+1
  }
  counts[i] = count
}  
counts
```

This gives me the same value for count that the non- for loop code did, but repeated 5 times.  So assuming that the count would be `8`, this code would return `8 8 8 8 8`

What I am hoping to return from the for loop is 5 separate counts, so that the output looks something like this (these numbers are arbitrary because of the random sample) `8 5 9 7 4`

Please help me to understand why this happens because I have had similar problems before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `x` and `count` within the for loop, otherwise `x` will already be > 10 on the second (and 3rd-5th) run through the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    x = 0
    count = 0
    while (x < 10) {
        y = sample(c(1,2), 1, c(.50,.50), replace = T)
        x = x+y
        count = count+1
    }
    counts[i] = count
}  
counts
```

Comment: Well explained. That is so simple but I would have never thought of that. Works great